# Google charts (GVisualizationPanel) breaks with ExtJS 4.1

Tags: extjs, google-visualization, extjs4.1

I am trying to use Google Charts (specifically Annotated Timeline) in conjunction with Ext JS 4.1. I came across [this tutorial](http://code.betancourt.us/ext-google-visualization/) which explains how Google Charts can be displayed in an Ext JS Panel using GVisualizationPanel.js.

Although it works beautifully with Ext JS 2.2 or 2.3, it does not seem to work with Ext JS 4.1 at all. You can see the output I get with version 4.1 below.

**Output with ExtJS 4.1**
 [Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRgEF.jpg)

As you can see there are no lines plotted in my example that uses Ext JS 4.1. The annotations are garbled too. I tried running the example with Ext JS 2.3 and it worked fine but using 2.3 is not an option for me.

Has anyone successfully integrated Google Charts with Ext JS 4.1?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. My own code had some bugs. Basically I had patched the GVisualizationPanel.js code to work with ExtJS 4.1 where the bug crept in. This bug resulted in the same (first) row being loaded into the DataTable multiple times. Hence there was data only at the beginning of the timeline. Thanks anyways.